# Skip word boundary in Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like this

```
test=1;toto=2;GSettings.key=value;GSettings.test=42;x=y;GSettings.aaa=bbb
```

what I  need is to use Regex to extract the string after the delimiter

**Output required:**

```
key=value

test=42

aaa=bbb
```

**What I have tried:** 
 regex

`GSettings.[^=]+=[^=;]+`but the GSettings is always included in the match pattern

here is [my test](http://rubular.com/r/GAh00jclYZ) on Rubular.com

**Note:**
I need a **`RegEx`** solution any other suggestions like using `string.Split` or `Linq` are not welcome

Comment: answer will be accepted for the best  explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Regex Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which will match but will not capture **GSettings** The syntax is pretty simple. Just use `(?<=MatchButDontCapture)capture+`

That should work in your case

```
(?<=GSettings\.)[^=]+=[^=;]+
```

---

You can also use [Capture Groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for more advanced matching. For example

`GSettings\.([^=]+)=([^=;]+) //The brackets are used for grouping`

Group 1 will hold the key while group 2 will hold the value

Answer (score 2):

Use [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
GSettings\.([^=]+=[^=;]+)
//       ^__ don't forget to escape the dot
```

The string you want will be in group 1.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=GSettings\.)[^=]+=[^=;]+
```

If your regex engine supports [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), you could also say:

```
GSettings\.\K[^=]+=[^=;]+
```

Comment: could you explain  more what you mean by look behind

Comment: @K.B What I meant was a _typo_!